# yammer get messages for groups followed Rest API

Tags: yammer

For the past few months, I've been using the GET /messages/my_feed.json API endpoint to get new messages for groups the user is following both public and private. The API is now returning different data.

After some testing, I've noticed that I get all the messages posted by the users in any of the groups they're following and messages that are posted as replies to their message or threaded group.

Was a change made to the API?

I'm looking for a way I can get all messages for groups that I'm following like I did prior with the GET /messages/my_feed.json endpoint.

Thak you guys in advanced.

Update: Once I post to a thread in a group I then get the messages via the API. Prior as long as I was following the group (As the documentation states) I would get the messages.

Update: GET messages/following.json is not working as expected either.

Update: Issues began after may 1st when yammer made these changes https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Yammer-Blog/Rationalizing-experiences-in-Yammer-and-Office-365/ba-p/185078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked into this and the change that you're seeing is due to a change that Yammer made with the My Feed algorithm. The best way to get new messages in a user's groups is to use the in_group messages endpoints.

Comment: This will not work for since for my app it would require me to poll every group a user is following eventually hitting the API limit.

Comment: Unfortunately the content of the my_feed and algo feeds are subject to change based on product requirements, like end user relevancy of feeds. Have you tried using the data export API? This should provide a super set of the data you need, but would require you to parse out what you need.

Comment: I have not Ill definitely look into it. But with the quick overlook I did, that seems like a very expensive endpoint to poll. The idea is to be notified(preferably with the message content) every time someone posts something to a group/thread I am following.